# DBAccess framework delete a record ios

Tags: ios, dbaccess

I am using `DBAccess` framework and would like to delete a record based on a condition however there is no example provided on Sample and Documentation. I see only one method `removeObjectWithIdentifier` in `DBFuzzystore` class but I am not using this class anywhere in my project. Is there a simple example where I would like to delete a record on a given condition. E.g. I would like to delete a record if record was created between a given date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, removals are made on result sets or individual objects.  For example.

```
[[[[MenuItem query] where:@"MenuTitle = 'Sample'"] fetch] removeAll];
```

or call remove on any single DBObject derived class.

```
for (MenuItem* item in [[[MenuItem query] where:@"MenuTitle = 'Sample'"] fetch]) {
    [item remove];
}
```

Hope this makes sense.